# error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_image.empty() && _image.type() == CV_8UC1 && (_image.isMat() || _image.isUMat()) in function 'cv::HoughCircles'

Tags: python, opencv

**Note :**

Hai, I'm new to OpenCV and Stackoverflow.

I'm trying to get the result by detecting a circle inside the circle using cv2.HoughCircles as my methods.

And here's a simple code that I tried already:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

pic= cv2.imread('septoria.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(pic,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

_,thres = cv2.threshold(gray, 50,260, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
res = cv2.Canny(thres, 100, 200, L2gradient=True)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(res,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=200,param2=25,minRadius=90,maxRadius=130)
for i in circles[0,:]:
    
    i = i.astype(int)
    crop = res[i[1]-i[2]:i[1]+i[2], i[0]-i[2]:i[0]+i[2]]
    mask = np.zeros(crop.shape)
    mask = cv2.circle(mask, (i[2], i[2]), i[2], (255, 255, 255), -1)
    final_im = mask * crop
    print(final_im.shape)
    circles2 = cv2.HoughCircles(final_im,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=20,param2=5,minRadius=0,maxRadius=20)
    for j in circles2[0,:]:
        cv2.circle(final_im,(int(j[0]),int(j[1])),int(j[2]),(255,0,0),2)

cv2.imshow('Hole',final_im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Final_im return shape (206, 206)

And give error like this

```
error: OpenCV(4.5.2) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-inblc7p7\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\hough.cpp:2253: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_image.empty() && _image.type() == CV_8UC1 && (_image.isMat() || _image.isUMat()) in function 'cv::HoughCircles'
```

The compiler said that I have wrong code in line 20:

```
circles2 = cv2.HoughCircles(final_im,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=20,param2=5,minRadius=0,maxRadius=20)
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in here, and tell me how to solve it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hough circles requires to have a unit8 image as an input, and if you chekc the type of finaly_im using `final_im.dtype`, it will most likely be a float64 image.

In order to change the image type, you can use:

```
final_im = mask * crop
final_im = cv2.normalize(src=final_im, dst=None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
```

Hough Circles documentation [link](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d) for further information

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: The normalization is redundant, it should be sufficient to initialize mask correctly -- `mask = np.zeros(crop.shape)` needs to have a dtype specified as second parameter,